# Process finished with exit code 132 (interrupted by signal 4: SIGILL) on Macbook Pro with M1 processor - Tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, apple-m1

I am trying to build a neural network in PyCharm using Tensorflow on a Macbook Pro with M1 processor. I use Professional PyCharm, macOS Big Sur 11.2. I tried to download python3 in multiple ways(thinking it wasn't correctly downloaded), finally I installed it using homebrew, so I have now python 3.9.4. After creating a virtual env in PyCharm, I set up the interpreter by installing Tensorflow and Keras 2.5.0rc1, then when I try to import tensorflow, I get this error : Process finished with exit code 132 (interrupted by signal 4: SIGILL). I don't understand what is the problem. Am I using a wrong interpreter(how does the architecture influence it) or am I missing any set up?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue, as found on the [tensorflow repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/46628). The solution given there is to use this [repo](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos) which is an official port of tensorflow for Macs with the M1 chip. It has a detailed guide on how to install. Which says all you have to do is download the latest release from here:

https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/releases

unpack the archive and finally run this command

```
/bin/bash ./tensorflow_macos/install_venv.sh --help
```

Unfortunately since I don't have an M1 mac I won't be able to test it out myself.